# Fail to create online meeting with application identity with GraphServiceClient

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm using an application identity from Azure AD with both read write permission granted, I've also run the Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy so that the application identity has right to create online meeting on behalf of a real user identity from Azure AD

I know my setup works with get user from the graph api. However, I'm getting error after running the following:

```
            var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0")
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .Build();

            GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient =
                new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta", new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
                {

                        var authResult = await confidentialClient
                            .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                            .ExecuteAsync();

                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
                })
                    );

                var onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting
                {
                    StartDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-12-25T21:30:34.2444915+00:00"),
                    EndDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-12-25T22:00:34.2464912+00:00"),
                    Subject = "User Token Meeting 1"
                    
                };

                var meetingInstance = await graphServiceClient.Me.OnlineMeetings
                    .Request()
                    .AddAsync(onlineMeeting);
```

The error message is as follow, why would it say ***User look up by user id failed in AAD***?

Status: NotFound (404)
OperationId: 8d06ff01-1dc3-49d1-9ced-9db6a919b162

ClientCorrelationId: 53b4478e-ba86-48ca-bb5b-25e5ef50c187

Server error: User lookup by user id failed in AAD.

Client exception: Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.

Inner error:

AdditionalData:

date: 2020-12-16T21:08:31

request-id: d60858cf-5ef5-4a0d-8d67-181f80ed6c35

client-request-id: d60858cf-5ef5-4a0d-8d67-181f80ed6c35

ClientRequestId: d60858cf-5ef5-4a0d-8d67-181f80ed6c35

at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendRequestAsync(Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync[T](Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
at MSTeam.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\VSTS\msteam\MSTeam\MSTeam\Program.cs:line 62

Comment: when you try with application identity then why you want to call as "me", which is meant for delegated identity. You should use "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user-id/onlinemeetings" api call and it will work for you.

Comment: what user-id should I put in there? I thought when I create the graphServiceClient, I already pass the client id and client secret of the application identity, so it would know it's from the application identity.

I've updated above on how I instantiated the graph client.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dev is correct.

Based on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp#http-request):

> Request when using an application token: `POST /users/{userId}/onlineMeetings`.

So you should use `graphServiceClient.Users["{userId}"].OnlineMeetings` instead of `graphServiceClient.Me.OnlineMeetings` here.

`userId` is the object ID of a user. When you [Configure application access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy#configure-application-access-policy), you need to grant the policy to the user:

```
Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -PolicyName Test-policy -Identity "ddb80e06-92f3-4978-bc22-a0eee85e6a9e"
```

`ddb80e06-92f3-4978-bc22-a0eee85e6a9e` is exactly the `userId`.

My code for your reference:

```
        // Configure the MSAL client as a confidential client
        var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create("{client_id}")
            .WithTenantId("{tenant_id}")
            .WithClientSecret("{client_secret}")
            .Build();

        ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClient);

        GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

        var onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting
        {
            StartDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2021-01-12T21:30:34.2444915+00:00"),
            EndDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2021-01-12T22:00:34.2464912+00:00"),
            Subject = "User Token Meeting123"
        };

        var meeting = await graphServiceClient.Users["{userId}"].OnlineMeetings
            .Request()
            .AddAsync(onlineMeeting);
```