# Microsoft Graph API beta OnlineMeetings Error - Server error: User lookup by user id failed in AAD

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am working on a slack app that calls Microsoft Graph API in order to generate a Microsoft Teams meeting link.

I am able to generate an access token, however I am getting the error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Status: NotFound (404)\r\nOperationId: 53deefa0-754d-451d-8d0b-34c94ecf1c8e\r\nClientCorrelationId: 4794ce56-5774-40c5-a272-b6e4cb1242ab\r\nServer error: User lookup by user id failed in AAD.\r\nClient exception: Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.\r\n",
    }
}
```

Because I use an application token, I am using the beta version of microsoft graph API

Here is my post request:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{Application Object ID}/onlineMeetings

{
    "startDateTime": "2020-12-28T14:30:34.2444915-07:00",
    "endDateTime" :  "2020-12-29T15:00:34.2464912-07:00",
    "subject" : "User Token Meeting",
    "participants": {
        "organizer": {
            "identity": {
                "user": {
                    "id": "Application client ID"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Microsoft docs unfortunately don't show an example for my use case, so I would really appreciate if someone could help me out.

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Comment: Since you are using application token, remember to [Configure application access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy#configure-application-access-policy). And you should put `user id` instead of `Application Object ID` in the request. For how to get the user id, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65405991/fail-to-create-online-meeting-with-application-identity-with-graphserviceclient?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: You put the wrong `user id` because you use the `Application Object ID`. AAD cannot find your user account by that id. That is why you get 404.

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you, you can accept it as an answer to end the thread( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) Thank you.

Comment: I went through all the steps, and I now get an "500 InternalServerError", anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0):

What @allen said is right, you should not put the `Application Object ID` in the request url, you need to put the `user id`.

You can also view the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#http-request):

[image]