# 403 Forbidden error when trying to create a meeting using MS Graph API in PHP

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, moodle

I am trying to create an online meeting using Graph API for MS Teams using the [PHP Graph API SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php).

I was able to get the bearer token, but when I try to create a meeting I get the error shown below. This is the code I used:

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');

use Microsoft\Graph\Graph;
use Microsoft\Graph\Model;

class UsageExample
{
    public function run()
    {
        $accessToken = 'xxxxxxxxxx';

        $graph = new Graph();
        $graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);

        $user = $graph->createRequest("POST", "/me/onlineMeetings")
                      ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
                      ->execute();

        echo "Hello, I am {$user->getGivenName()}.";
    }
}

$da = new UsageExample();

print_r($da->run());
```

[image]

I have given the permissions also
[image]

THis is the post man api with response[image]

Comment: What do you have at the moment?

Comment: I didn't get any docs for php core. only it is available for laravel SDK. Any way to do it via API  @CTABUYO

Comment: What do you mean? https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php is for any PHP, it has no relationship with Laravel.

Comment: I have Client ID & Client Secret ID whereas that is for Laravel i need it for Core PHP when i went through the  https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php it is not even showing autoload.php

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "that is for Laravel". None of it has anything to do with Laravel at all. Laravel is just a framework, it has absolutely no effect on how you connect to the graph API. The process is the same from any PHP application. In fact it's the same from any application written in any programming language, only the SDK code varies slightly. You don't even _need_ the SDK technically, you can write the HTTP requests yourself if you wish.

Comment: It's unclear why an autoload.php would cause you a problem either. You can install it with composer, or by hand, or whatever. But if you're having a specific problem, please be specific about it.

Comment: Can you please provide me a sample copy if any..... Thanks!

Comment: There's already samples in the link I gave you. Where exactly are you stuck? You aren't being clear or specific about the problem

Comment: 403 Forbidden` response: {"error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. I am getting this error

Comment: You get this error when you do what _exactly_? Please edit your question with the code and that error info, thanks. See also [ask] and how to create a [mre]

Comment: I have updated the code and the error. Please check

Comment: I see, thankyou. Well then it seems the account you logged into the API with does not have permission to create a meeting. You should check their permissions in the portal first of all.

Comment: P.S. in future please paste error messages as text, not screenshots. Then people can google them, or quote them into answers, and they are searchable by others who are experiencing the same error, etc. None of that is possible from a picture. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much i will follow that. Can you please help me to set what are the permission do i need to set

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http lists the permissions

Comment: P.S. It's also possible that an error is occuring because you didn't provide any details of the meeting in the request. You have to supply the meeting information in the request body.

Comment: I have given the permission also please recheck the question now please

Comment: Compared to your PostMan request, in your PHP you are not sending any meeting details.

Comment: I am not getting the output when i try in postman with meetings details. At least it should have work in post right

Comment: The postman error is an authentication one, seems the token you used there is invalid.  So it's clearly a different problem, which occurs before it tries to create the meeting. And that wasn't my point. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/wiki/Example-calls gives examples of how to attach body data to a request using the SDK.

Comment: @imraj, while trying in postman try with [access token without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0), steps are clearly written there. For the Graph API you are calling you need to add **application permission** accordingly.

Comment: The issue related PHP API is it solved?

Comment: Have you tried solution above?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what method you are using to get access token, but here are the two ways to get access token:

1. [Get access token without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0)
2. [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?view=graph-rest-beta)

Please refer [Create Event](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/wiki/Example-calls#create-an-event) (available in same link you shared) on how to make POST call.

While trying in postman try with [access token without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0), steps are clearly written there. Please add application permission accordingly.

Comment: while i try getting this {
    "error": {
        "code": "General",
        "message": "User not found.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "6ba6a149-7a94-41a3-892a-1bd3c6336d04",
            "date": "2021-08-10T11:03:59",
            "client-request-id": "6ba6a149-7a94-41a3-892a-1bd3c6336d04"
        }
    }
}

Comment: While getting access token? Have followed the steps mention in doc?

Comment: Yes i have followed @Hunaid Hanfee-MSFT

Comment: Error seems like, you are providing the wrong user-id. Follow this to get user id:
1. [Get a user](https://www.bing.com/newtabredir?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fgraph%2Fapi%2Fuser-get) 2. Got to Azure portal -> Users and get it from there.

Comment: Also, if you are using application permission then you need to use this endpoint : `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/onlineMeetings`. Refer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65405991/fail-to-create-online-meeting-with-application-identity-with-graphserviceclient) for more information.